# pyffmpeg segmentation fault on osx

Tags: python, macos, ffmpeg, cython, pyffmpeg

I am having trouble installing and using pyffmpeg in OSX. (Snow Leopard)

I tried different versions. Only configuration that seems to install is Python2.6, Cython 0.13 and pyffmpeg 2.0. (Python, ffmpeg and cython is installed with MacPorts and pyffmpeg with setup.py)

But with that when I try to open a file

```
stream=pyffmpeg.VideoStream()
stream.open(filepath)
```

it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 24, in test
    stream.open(filepath)
  File "pyffmpeg.pyx", line 2467, in pyffmpeg.VideoStream.open (pyffmpeg.c:16607)
  File "pyffmpeg.pyx", line 1920, in pyffmpeg.FFMpegReader.open (pyffmpeg.c:11361)
IOError: Unable to open file test.mp4 (url_fopen)
Segmentation fault
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I had the impression this was in very early alpha stage; I tried to install on both windows and linux not all that long ago and didn't succeed at either.  Will be curious if it's at the point where it's expected to work.

Comment: @profane, it works fine on Ubuntu on a friend's pc.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I'll have to check it out again on that platform.  Sorry to see you haven't found anyone who can help with your problem.  What are you hoping to do with it?

Comment: @profane, I just ditched pyffmpeg altogether and switched to opencv.